# Windows 7 folder name improve max character length

Tags: windows-7, directory

i want to improve  windows 7 folder name  character length. default character length is 260. 
Have you Any suggestion about this problem ?

Comment: This might be more appropriate on http://superuser.com/

Comment: Windows supports file/folder names of about 32000 characters.  Prefix the path name with `\\?\\`.  There's just a wholelotta software that will keel over badly when you go past the winapi MAX_PATH.  259 chars, not 260.  Don't do it.